# Path to link css file to html page

Tags: html, css, file, path

I would like to ask a little help to link my stylesheet file to my html pages...

```
public
 index.html
>assets
 >css
  file.css
 >js
 >img
>pages
 page1.html
 page2.html
```

I tried to link my stylesheet like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/basic.css">
```

but it doesn't work.

Moreover, i can't link also the index.html in page1.html. I put this tag in page1.html and it doesn't work:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok I've done.
My problem was that file.css is located in the folder one level up from the current folder so that I have to describe the path starting with ../